# Regular Expression to match extension file depending of the drive letter

Tags: regex

I have this regex which can detect specific extension file,

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-\(\):])+(.cmd|.exe|.bat)$
```

but I would like to change it so that it never applies to c:\ , the goal is to detect these extension files only on secondary or external drives

Example

```
D:\test.bat match
c:\test.bat does not match
```

Thank you

Comment: Regex is not and should not be the solution to everything. What programming language are you using? Have you investigated whether it has built in classes to handle parsing of file paths so that you can pull the drive letter and file extension? Are the file paths always valid?

Comment: Hi Jeff, i do not have the choice about this, it's mandatory a regex query to implement in my EDR (indicator of attack feature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pattern that you tried, you have to escape the dot to match it literally, and you don't have to escape the dot or the parenthesis in the character class.

Note that `\s` could also match a newline.

For the listed examples, you can make use of a negetive lookahead if supported, to rule out `c:\` or `C:\`

Without the capture groups, to get a match only:

```
  ^(?![cC]:\\)[a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.():-]+\.(?:cmd|exe|bat)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?![cC]:\\)` Negative lookahead to assert what is directly to the right is not `c:\` or `C:\`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.():-]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed in the character class
- `\.(?:cmd|exe|bat)` Match a dot, and 1 of the alternatives
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M3lGlB/1)

Or with the capture groups:

```
^(?![cC]:\\)([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.():-]+)(\.(?:cmd|exe|bat))$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FzpztX/1)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every path is in a separate **line** based on the `$` you included in your pattern, here's a very simple solution you can build upon:

```regex
^[^cC].*(cmd|exe|bat)$
```

Explanation:

- `^` matches the beginning of a line.
- `[^cC]` matches everything *except* `c` or `C`.
- `.*` matches any character except line terminators, zero or more times.
- `(cmd|exe|bat)` matches your extensions. Since the dot was matched in the previous line, there's no need to match it again.
- `$` matches end of line.

> **TL;DR**: you forgot to match the beginning of your lines.